how to start openvpnas at reboot?
Since a couple of weeks, when my server (Ubuntu 20.04LTS) restarts, openvpnas does not start correctly and leaves messages likes the ones hereunder in the openvpnas log.
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info] Server Agent initialization status:
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info] {
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]   "errors": {
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_web": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "error",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: {'web'}"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_0": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "info",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "process started successfully on 172.27.224.1"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_1": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "info",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "process started successfully on 172.27.228.1"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_2": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "info",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "process started successfully on 172.27.232.1"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_3": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "info",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "process started successfully on 172.27.236.1"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "web": [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "error",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "process started but is unresponsive: "
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ],
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       [
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "error",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]         "service failed to start or returned error status"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]       ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     ]
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]   },
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]   "last_restarted": "Mon Apr 22 05:02:37 2024",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]   "service_status": {
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "api": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "auth": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "bridge": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "client_query": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "crl": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "daemon_pre": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "db_push": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "ip6tables_live": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "ip6tables_openvpn": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_api": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_live": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_openvpn": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_web": "off. Error: [Error: service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: {'web'}.]",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "log": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_0": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_1": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_2": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_3": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "subscription": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "user": "started",
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]     "web": "off. Error: [Error: service failed to start or returned error status.]"
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info]   }
2024-04-22T05:04:11+0200 [stdout#info] }

However, if I restart it later, everything runs correctly, without errors.  What can I do to prevent this? Right now, I put a restart command in cron but this is not ideal.
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]   "service_status": {
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "api": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "auth": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "bridge": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "client_query": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "crl": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "daemon_pre": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "db_push": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "ip6tables_live": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "ip6tables_openvpn": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_api": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_live": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_openvpn": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "iptables_web": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "log": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_0": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_1": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_2": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "openvpn_3": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "subscription": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "user": "started",
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]     "web": "started"
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info]   }
2024-04-22T07:00:39+0200 [stdout#info] }


You should check the logs as to why the wb component is failing.

First check the status after startup of the openvpn service with:
systemctl list-units --type=service
If not activated and running follow the instructions here:
How can I configure a service to run at startup

It is activated (and always has been).  Only, it fails when started at boot time and succeeds later.
